# How to find the convergence radius of this complex series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I know how to do it find the convergence radius when the series is in the following format using Cauchy's formula. z is a complex number in this case.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$$

where:

$$R = \frac{1}{\lim_{n\to \infty}
|a_n|^{1/n}}$$

For instance if I have:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \ n z^{7n}$$

I would write, $7n = k,$ $ a_k = \frac{k}{7}$ then proceed with the $R.$

Now I have a series like this:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}(z+7)^{n}$$

How do I calculate the convergence radius in this case? I am stuck.

Comment: Replacing $z$ with $z+7$ doesn't change the radius of convergence calculation, which only depends on $a_n$. It just means that $R$ is the distance from $-7$ where absolute convergence occurs.

Comment: thanks a lot this makes it clear to me

Comment: Technically, the value is $$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}}$$ If the limit exists, your formula works, but $\limsup$ always works.

Comment: The “+7” changes the center of the region of convergence, not the radius.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I didnt write it because I am new to the forum and due to the parenthesis it kept giving errors :)

Answer (score 2):

Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}\right|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac13=\frac13,$$the radius of convergence is $3$.

Comment: so (z+7)^n has no effect?

Comment: None whatsoever, as far as the computation of the radius of convergence is concerned.